# ElasticSearch Couchbase integration

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

Basically I have followed the instructions [here](http://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-and-full-text-search-couchbase-transport-elastic-search)

But when I go to couchbase to setup the replication i get:

[image]

but I know it is there because

[image]

The machines can ping each other and no firewalls etc.....

I have found the following error in the log for elaticsearch every time i hit replicate in couchbase.

[image]

I am not sure what this means but....

Any pointers would be appreciated

Kindest Regards

Robin

Edit
Ps: lastest version of both couchbase and elasticsearch from today and running ubuntu server 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the CouchBase plugin has not been released yet for Elasticsearch 0.20.x but only for 0.19.x.

I think this is your issue here.

So try switching to a 0.19.9 ES version or wait for the next release of the CouchBase plugin.

Comment: Yep that was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: For you information a log as been created to capture this issue and fix it the next release of the Couchbase Elastic Search Plugin : http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/CBES-6

Comment: Thanks for the update. Look forward to a new release. Ps: Been working all day with 19.9. Works as expected till now. No problems.